# Unable to interface moveit with gazebo - Controllers not loaded and unable to spawn robot model

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to interface moveit with gazebo for simulation.
I'm following **the construct sim tutorial** for the same,  **which uses ubuntu 16.04 and ros-kinetic**
https://www.theconstructsim.com/control-gazebo-simulated-robot-moveit-video-answer/

**I'm using ros-melodic and ubuntu 18.04 with gazebo - version 9.12

Linux 5.3.0-42-generic x86_64
HP pavillion notebook**
UR package that i downloaded for urdf from melodic-devel branch
https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/tree/melodic-devel

Question 1 : I'm unable to see the action servers having type of controller **FollowJointTrajectory** as it is given in the tutorial when i run [ $ rostopic list ] after launching ur5.launch in the ur package

Terminal shows this

```
$ rostopic list
/calibrated
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/joint_group_position_controller/command
/joint_states
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

and i suppose this could be one of the reasons of not getting the controllers loaded to gazebo.

The model also gets loaded to gazebo which is very translucent as in i think it is not spawned correctly and i recieve this error

```
    $ roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5.launch 
    
    Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
    Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
    Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
    
    xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
    started roslaunch server http://xxxx-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-xxxxxxx/
    
    SUMMARY
    ========
    
    PARAMETERS
     * /arm_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
     * /arm_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
     * /arm_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
     * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
     * /arm_controller/state_publish_rate: 25
     * /arm_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
     * /arm_controller/type: position_controll...
     * /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
     * /joint_group_position_controller/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
     * /joint_group_position_controller/type: position_controll...
     * /joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
     * /joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
     * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
     * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 50.0
     * /robot_state_publisher/tf_prefix: 
     * /rosdistro: melodic
     * /rosversion: 1.14.5
     * /use_sim_time: True
    
    NODES
      /
        arm_controller_spawner (controller_manager/controller_manager)
        fake_joint_calibration (rostopic/rostopic)
        gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
        gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
        joint_state_controller_spawner (controller_manager/controller_manager)
        robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
        ros_control_controller_manager (controller_manager/controller_manager)
        spawn_gazebo_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
    
    auto-starting new master
    process[master]: started with pid [24412]
    ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
    
    setting /run_id to 8a547ef4-75d3-11ea-bcec-302432c29868
    process[rosout-1]: started with pid [24423]
    started core service [/rosout]
    process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [24430]
    process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [24435]
    process[spawn_gazebo_model-4]: started with pid [24440]
    process[robot_state_publisher-5]: started with pid [24441]
    process[fake_joint_calibration-6]: started with pid [24442]
    process[joint_state_controller_spawner-7]: started with pid [24448]
    process[arm_controller_spawner-8]: started with pid [24450]
    process[ros_control_controller_manager-9]: started with pid [24451]
    [ INFO] [1585936203.649255599]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
    [ INFO] [1585936203.651239013]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
    [ INFO] [1585936203.713316303]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
    [ INFO] [1585936203.715368125]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
    [INFO] [1585936203.982848, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter robot_description
    [INFO] [1585936203.991291, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
    [ INFO] [1585936204.108098098]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
    [ INFO] [1585936204.176096535, 0.061000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
    [INFO] [1585936204.297095, 0.174000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
    [INFO] [1585936204.624149, 0.348000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity
    [ INFO] [1585936204.675743037, 0.348000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
    [ INFO] [1585936204.675917775, 0.348000000]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /
    [ INFO] [1585936204.677101870, 0.348000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
    [ERROR] [1585936204.799004180, 0.348000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/shoulder_pan_joint
    [ERROR] [1585936204.800050099, 0.348000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/shoulder_lift_joint
    [ERROR] [1585936204.801109164, 0.348000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/elbow_joint
    [ERROR] [1585936204.802086064, 0.348000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_1_joint
    [ERROR] [1585936204.802965703, 0.348000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_2_joint
    [ERROR] [1585936204.803927588, 0.348000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_3_joint
    [ INFO] [1585936204.809656297, 0.348000000]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
    [spawn_gazebo_model-4] process has finished cleanly
  
    Loaded 'joint_state_controller'
    Started ['joint_state_controller'] successfully
    [ERROR] [1585936204.891563571, 0.398000000]: Could not load controller 'arm_controller' because controller type 'position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController' does not exist.
    [ERROR] [1585936204.891626027, 0.398000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
    Error when loading 'arm_controller'
    [ERROR] [1585936204.895865189, 0.403000000]: Could not start controller with name 'arm_controller' because no controller with this name exists
    Error when starting ['arm_controller'] and stopping []
    Loaded 'joint_group_position_controller'
    [joint_state_controller_spawner-7] process has finished cleanly
    log file
    [arm_controller_spawner-8] process has finished cleanly
   log file
    [ros_control_controller_manager-9] process has finished cleanly
    log file
    [ WARN] [1585936973.534349503, 638.841000000]: Shutdown request received.
    [ WARN] [1585936973.535242619, 638.841000000]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
    [ERROR] [1585936974.053903144, 639.253000000]: SpawnModel: Failure - model name robot already exist.
    [ WARN] [1585937062.800113468, 710.530000000]: Shutdown request received.
    [ WARN] [1585937062.805011167, 710.532000000]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]
    [robot_state_publisher-5] process has finished cleanly

    [ERROR] [1585937067.597536341, 712.694000000]: SpawnModel: Failure - model name robot already exist.
    [gazebo_gui-3] process has finished cleanly
```

As i follow the tutorials further and do the exact same replacements in the config and launch folders of the demo_moveit_config package created by the moveit_setup_assistant

**Please check the link of the tutorial for the controllers.yaml file if i have missed some information**

and at the end launch the demo_planning_execution.launch i get this error

```
$ roslaunch demo_moveit_config demo_planning_execution.launch 

Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

RLException: unused args [config] for include of [/home/xxxxx/ns_ws/src/demo_moveit_config/launch/moveit_rviz.launch]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

for clarification i'm also uploading moveit_rviz.launch

```
<launch>

  <arg name="debug" default="false" />
  <arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="" />
  <arg     if="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="gdb --ex run --args" />

  <arg name="rviz_config" default="" />
  <arg     if="$(eval rviz_config=='')" name="command_args" value="" />
  <arg unless="$(eval rviz_config=='')" name="command_args" value="-d $(arg rviz_config)" />

  <node name="$(anon rviz)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" respawn="false"
    args="$(arg command_args)" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find demo_moveit_config)/config/kinematics.yaml"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

**THIS IS HOW I'M UNABLE TO INTERFACE MOVEIT WITH GAZEBO**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348345/unable-to-interface-moveit-with-gazebo---controllers-not-loaded-and-unable-to-spawn-robot-model/) by [R_CODEC](https://answers.ros.org/users/53195/r_codec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the error after upgrading the ros-control-package
Now it's working.

---

Originally posted by [R_CODEC](https://answers.ros.org/users/53195/r_codec/) with karma: 16 on 2020-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0